# cakephp Simple Tagging Behavior equivalent in 2.x

Tags: cakephp, error-handling, tags, tagging

I'm trying to make use of http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dooltaz/2007/05/02/simple-tagging-behavior but the code on /app/models/behaviors/tag.php is causing this error: "

> Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

"..

I changed `function setup(&$model` to  `function setup(Model $model` and the likes already.. Also changed the filename from **tag.php** to **TagBehavior.php**..

I'm guessing it's because of  `$Tag =& new Tag;` since it's near `$res = $Tag->find(`.. How can I convert this to 2.x (I'm using cake 2.4.3)? And what else is causing this error?

Comment: maybe the whole behavior is to be rewritten, but did you try changing into `$Tag = new Tag()`?

Comment: yup @arilia. tried that but didn't work. i don't think the whole script needs to be rewritten. just the parts that are no longer compatible with the new version maybe.

Comment: The script isn't well written in my opinion, here https://github.com/CakeDC/tags there's a cakeDC tag plugin, maybe take a look. Anyway, did you try `$Tag = $this->Tag`?

Answer (score 0):

That plugin is ancient, it is 6 years old and has no tests at all nor does it seem to be well written at all.

Try the [CakeDC Tags plugin](https://github.com/cakedc/tags) instead.

Comment: Yeah. Tried that but it's giving me some issues.I guess I have to do it my own way instead.

Comment: Well, and what issues does it give you? I doubt you're going to do it quicker and better your own way given the amount of time that went into the plugin. Good luck.